# AWS RDS Read replica high Write Throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am having a strange issue with my Amazon RDS read replica. The monitoring says it has much higher Wite Throughput than the master instance. Master is the same instance class, xlarge. Also, write IOPS metric looks higher. [image: Read replica is orange]

What may cause the higher write in read replica?

Comment: Temporary tables from `SELECT` queries would be an obvious candidate.  Are you actively querying the replica?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing lots of queries there, but there is only one stored procedure that uses temporary table and does it periodically (every 12 hour). I examined my other SELECT statements and it seems that my LIMIT is sometimes over 2000 while joining big tables. 
If i don't have enough freeable memory, will the DB engine write result sets to disk?

Comment: Whether results are written to disk isn't related to available memory.  The query plan and the size of any necessary temporary tables (created implicitly by the optimized for the duration of one query and immediately destroyed) are the major considerations.  Are you familiar with [using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to view query plans?

Comment: Yes, I know a bit about `EXPLAIN`. I examined my "heavy" queries and all of them use indexes. Unfortunately I cannot post the output of `EXPLAIN` due to the company rules but I found extra information  "Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort". The `Using temporary; Using filesort` may increase the write throughput?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  `Using temporary` means disk writes except under certain conditions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html.  The amount of read != write for many possible reasons, including temp tables with `LIMIT` where the `LIMIT` is late in the plan, and reads that are obviated by incidental use of the OS cache.

Comment: Your comments helped solving my issue. You may put this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!